# In IPad How to keep leftBarButtonItem active in ladscape mode?

Tags: ipad

I am trying to implement following scenario in the IPad environment.

I have list of some information with me and that list is shown on the master view from which user select the particular item and its details is shown on the detail page.

Now I need to show the next and prev button on the navigation bar,so that user can navigate from that button as well instead of selecting the item from the master list.

for that I have used the UIToolbar to show the customized buttons,but now I am facing two issue

1. How to get the link of prev backbutton which show the popover of master view.
2. How to keep these customized buttons live in the landscape mode.

Please help on this.

Thanks,

Sagar....

Comment: Do you mean something like MobileNotes.app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about adding buttons on UIToolbar of Detail View ?  They will be visible on both landscape and portrait mode.

Comment: Thanks Sujee for reply but I am not able to understand where shall I invoke this navigationbar updation. as it seems when I rotate the button get vanish...

Comment: if you want to catch the rotation:

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration { }

in view controller